# How do I conditionally skip a scenario in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How do I conditionally skip a scenario?

For example, I wish to continue a scenario only if certain conditions are met, but I do not want it to register as a failure if it's not present.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Cucumber is not meant to be conditional, its' meant to be used in place of a functional requirement spec. The customer's requirements are not conditional. You should just expand your 'Given' clause... `Given A but not B`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DanPantry so if the Given returns false, doesn't it result in a failed test? i want something like skipped if possible :(

Comment: If `Given` "returns" false, you shouldn't be executing the test. `Given` is meant to be a way to say "This test is valid under these conditions". In other words, `Given a Knife and Slice of Bread`, `When I press cut the Bread with the Knife`, `Then I should have two halves of the Slice of Bread`. This test wouldn't hold up if you had a `Can of Beans` instead of a `Slice of Bread`. TLDR if Given "returns" false (it doesn't return) then you aren't testing known/planned behaviour

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue I had. The tests I write are against a UI that has a constantly changing BE database that I am currently unable to have static data in.
This means that some times it is possible that there is no data for the test.
Not a pass not a fail, just unable to run.

The way that I found to work best was to invoke a cucumber pending.

example test:

```
Scenario: Test the application
  Given my application has data
  When I test something
  Then I get a result
```

example step def:

```
Given /^my application has data$/ do
  pending unless application.has_data?
end
```

These are the kind of results I can see:

```
201 scenarios (15 pending, 186 passed)
1151 steps (15 pending, 1136 passed)
```

It's worth noting that I have extra debugging and have these tests tagged so that at any time I can run these pending tests again.

Hope this helps,
Ben.

Comment: This solution trows a pending error for me and marks the tests as failed in the final summary

Comment: Are you running cucumber with the strict flag?
[look here](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/cli/strict-mode#fail-with---strict-due-to-pending-step)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this:
Apart from using `pending`, or a specific profile to skip scenarios with certain tags, there are at least 2 more ways to achieve this.

I can understand why you would need this, as I had a similar problem and got a solution, hence worth sharing.
In my case, I had a piece of functionality expected to be available on 3/10 devices, and expected to be not available on the remaining 7.

*Caveats with using 'pending' to skip:*

- Since the tests and code were implemented, it didn't feel right to mark steps as `pending`.
- It caused confusion, as it was difficult to distinguish really `pending` scenarios from skipped but marked `pending` scenarios at the end of a run
- Some CI jobs (Jenkins/Hudson) might be configured to fail for pending scenarios, hence causing more trouble.

So, I rather wanted to just skip them during execution depending on the condition of which browser is being used. I also didn't want to have too many profiles specific to certain browsers/devices

*Solution*:

1. Use cucumber.yml to skip tagged scenarios conditionally

Here's a known ignored interesting fact about cucumber (from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml):

> The cucumber.yml file is preprocessed by ERb; this allows you to use ruby code to generate values in the cucumber.yml file

- Building on this, tag your scenarios with something unique, say `@conditional`

  - At the beginning of your cucumber config (cucumber.yml), apply your conditional logic **outside** of any profiles mentioned:

    `<% included = (ENV['BROWSER'] =~ /chrome/) ? "-t @conditional" : "-t ~@conditional" %>`

    `included` is just a variable, which will have a value of tags to include/exclude depending on the condition
  - Now use this conditional variable in the default profile
    `default: <%= included %>`

So now your default profile will use the included/excluded tests as identified by your conditional logic.

2. (More complicated and not elegant) Use rake tasks for cucumber execution:

Conditionally choose tags to include/exclude within your rake task, and pass them to cucumber execution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very detailed answer, I should give this a go some day, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could check the condition before you start cucumber, then use a profile that would skip the scenarios with certain tags. Put this in your cucumber.yml:

```
default: --tags ~@wip --tags ~@broken --no-source --color 
limited: --tags @core --tags ~@wip --tags ~@broken --no-source --color
```

Replace @core with whatever tag you use for the cukes you want to run (or use ~ to exclude cukes). Then run the limited profile from a shell script that checks the conditions:

```
cucumber -p limited
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see this solution which truly skips the scenario instead of trowing a pending error:

```
Before do |scenario|
      scenario.skip_invoke!
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am tagging my scenarios, and then in my "step_definitions/hooks.rb" file, I have something like this:

```
Before('@proxy') do 
  skip_this_scenario unless proxy_running?
end
```

`scenario.skip_invoke!` which was mentioned in another answer seems to be deprecated.