# How to ignore particular example in cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

As a test automation engineer. I'd like to exclude some examples in runtime.
For example:

```
Scenario: Some simple scenario
 Given I logged in as <local> user
 When  I visit home page
 Then  I should see <local> logo

Examples: User
 |local|
 |UK   |
#ignore 'Spain'
 |Spain|
```

Comment: Put a hash symbol before this example. Cucumber code is a ruby code.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I'd like to do that in runtime @mudasobwa

Comment: AFAIK, one can not skip _examples_, but it’s possible to [effectively skip scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303948/how-do-i-conditionally-skip-a-scenario-in-cucumber). So, split the code above into two scenarios and conditionally skip the latter.

Comment: That's not a good solution for me.

Comment: Then your option is to patch cucumber source code.

Comment: Actually, no. Take a look at the answer below from @Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach I'd suggest is to use [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags):

```
Scenario Outline: Some simple scenario
  Given I logged in as <local> user
  When  I visit home page
  Then  I should see <local> logo

  Examples:
    | local |
    | UK    |

  @wip
  Examples:
    | local |
    | Spain |
```

This will, by default, skip the "work in progress" tests. There are also [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983793/1954610) you could take, to run the tests as "expected failures".

Answer (score 2):

its possible to run just one example from the outline by using the line number, so if your UK example was on line 8 of `simple.feature` you could run

`cucumber features/simple.feature:8`

There is no way to run a bunch of features and exclude a particular scenario without tagging or modifying the feature file as far as I'm aware. Run `cucumber --help` to get full details. Personally I can't understand why you would want to do this, perhaps you could explain why you want to do this and give an example, there might be alternative workflows that would work for you.